# Making program take actual time to execute C++

Tags: c++, time

I'm trying to simulate a real life scenario that takes actual time using C++; I am using a for loop to break up time into five-minute increments.

I want to know if there is any way to tell the program to only execute through one step of the for loop every second? This way the program would become "watchable".

Comment: `for (;;) { do_stuff(); sleep(1); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the current time and add the frequency, the perform you actin and wait until the calculated time. Like so.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

//...

while(whatever_condition()) {
    auto next=std::chrono::system_clock::now() 
             +std::chrono::seconds(1);

    do_whatever();

    std::this_thread::sleep_until(next);
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until

Note using the plain "sleep" and "usleep" functions are nonstandard, and will NOT take into account the amount of time the operation takes.

EDIT:
This is a c++11 solution, however if don't have C++11 boost provides this functionality too for C++98 and 03. I believe that is still preferable to using `sleep`

Comment: Perhaps note that this requires C++11. I believe that at this time both GCC and MSVC++ have decent support for these features.

Comment: yes GCC has had this for a while. No idea about MSVC but MS have been touting that their stdlib feature complete for a while.

Comment: Well this is gonna open prove my true noobness to you but, what is C++11, c++98, and C++03? I have never heard of anything more than just c++

Comment: C++ is a standardised language, there are different version of the standard. C++11 is the newest standard and has added a lot of new features language and library to C++. you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11  if you can let me know what compiler version you are using I can probably let you know whether or not you have it. (for gcc try the --std=c++11 flag)

Comment: My compiler is g++ on the mac. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @aprohl5 type `g++ --version` into you shell. Also see if you have a copy of clang about `clang++ --version`

Comment: Austins-MacBook-Pro-2:bank austinprohl$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Austins-MacBook-Pro-2:bank austinprohl$ clang --version
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix

Comment: yes, I recommend using `clang++ -std=c++11` to compile you code. gcc 4.2 is way out of date. That said if you can upgrade you compilers to the newest versions that would be great, I can't help you there I don't know what the deal is with OSX and updating tools.

Comment: @aprohl5 if this answer helped you can you mark it correct so it can go on to help others thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With sleep you can have the program wait. I don't know if this is what you intend. So to wait one second, you type:

> sleep(1000)

Answer (score 0):

How important is it that it runs at a consistent rate? `sleep()` is one possible method of doing this, but `sleep` is pretty poor at delivering exact time slices. Games, of course, need to do this all the time so games programmers have explored a whole variety of ways of doing this, you can find a discussion of how to implement a game loop [here](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/). The central theory is to regularly check the timer and update according to produce the desired number of frames-per-second.

Comment: sleep is non standard and does different things on different OS's (MS param is milliseconds, POSIX seconds). There are standardised equivelants.